# How did Rita realized that she has lost the power?

Tags: edge-of-tomorrow

How did Rita realize that she has lost the power?

She said that due to another human's blood in her system she lost the power. But this doesn't explain how she was aware of the fact that she has lost the power. As to realize it you have to die and never wake up.